# How to replace repeating characters in a string with a single instance of the same character?

Tags: sql-server, regex, replace

I have a column of urls with some of the urls like [www.google.com///](http://www.google.com///)
Need them to be [www.google.com/](http://www.google.com/) instead.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the replace function?

Answer (score 1):

A triple replace should do the trick for you.

Consider the following data example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(my_col varchar(255) );

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
('www////wwwww'),
('www.google.com////'),
('www.google.com///'),
('www.google.com//'),
('www.google.com/'),
('www.google.com////////////'),
('////////www.google.com/');
```

Use:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(my_col, '/', '><'), '<>',''), '><','/') as new_my_col
FROM  mytable
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> new_my_col
> www/wwwww
> www.google.com/
> www.google.com/
> www.google.com/
> www.google.com/
> www.google.com/
> /www.google.com/
> ```
>
> How this query works ?

Th first replace would replace `/` with `><` giving below result :

```
new_my_col_step1
www><><><><wwwww
www.google.com><><><><
www.google.com><><><
www.google.com><><
www.google.com><
www.google.com><><><><><><><><><><><><
><><><><><><><><www.google.com><
```

In the second replace we change `<>` with empty , leaving only `><` which we replace on the last replace.

All the steps can be found on this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ENANcfSm)

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079764/replace-multiple-repeating-character-to-one) and [Overview of the SQL REPLACE function](https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-the-sql-replace-function/#:%7E:text=SELECT%20REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(,within%20the%20SQL%20REPLACE%20function.))))